# Problems with encryption and decryption TripleDES in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, encryption

I'm practicing encryption and decryption with a text file by using TipleDES. I enter a word in a text box, which is in my application, and then click my button that will store the password in the text file. I check the text file to see if it encrypts it which it does and then I try to decrypt the text. It encrypts it again and doesn't decrypt it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Public Function EncryptTripleDES(strInput As String, btKey As String) As String
    Dim desTDES As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim hashMD5TDES As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim btHash As Byte()
    Dim btBuff As Byte()
    btHash = hashMD5TDES.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(btKey))
    desTDES.Key = btHash
    desTDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    btBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strInput)
    Dim strResult As String = Convert.ToBase64String _
     (desTDES.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(btBuff, 0,
      btBuff.Length))
    Return strResult
End Function
Public Function DecryptTripleDES(strInput As String, btKey As String) As String
    Dim desTDES As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim hashMD5TDES As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim btHash As Byte()
    Dim btBuff As Byte()
    btHash = hashMD5TDES.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(btKey))
    desTDES.Key = btHash
    desTDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    btBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(strInput)
    Dim strResult As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString _
     (desTDES.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(btBuff, 0,
      btBuff.Length))
    Return strResult
End Function
```

These are my functions to encrypt and decrypt.

```
strEncode = EncryptTripleDES(EmailPasswordTextBox.Text, "HTG")
strDecode = DecryptTripleDES(strEncode, "HTG")
Console.WriteLine("Encrypted: {0}", strEncode)
Console.WriteLine("Decrypted: {0}", strDecode)
```

If I change `EmailPasswordTextBox.Text` to "This is a Test". It works perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Passwords should not be encrypted - salt them and then hash them.

Comment: I'm not storing them on a database. I'm just practicing encryption and decryption. I'm just trying to figure out why if I type "This is a test" it encrypts and decrypts perfectly fine, but reading from a text file it ecrypts it again and doesn't decrypt.